# How do I interpret a fillet indication on a technical drawing

Tags: cad, technical-drawing

I'm reproducing in Fusion 360 an object based on a technical drawing, but I have trouble understanding what this means:

[image]

When I read the Wikipedia article on [Engineering drawing, abbreviations and symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_drawing_abbreviations_and_symbols#R), it states:

> Radius of an arc or circle. Flats and reversals (falling within the dimensional tolerance zone) are tolerated unless "CR" (controlled radius) is explicitly specified.

But I still don't understand how this radius is being measured and therefore how to reproduce it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Measure 12.7 from both edges and the intersection gives the radius centre.